# Try serialize new XML file with Generic object

Tags: c#, xml, file, xmlserializer, generic-list

I am trying to creat an xml file, using serialize, with a custom class, and I am getting an exception:
"There was an error generating the xml document."

I tryed it with a list of strings, and it works, but not with a custom type...
Does any one have an idia why?

```
public class MyXML
{
    List<MyClass> Mylist;
    public XmlSerializer serialize;

    public MyXML()
    {
        Mylist=new List<MyClass>();
        serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
    }

    public void Save(List<MyClass> newList)
    {
        using (FileStream writer = File.OpenWrite(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()  + "/files/MyNewFile.xml"))
        { serialize.Serialize(writer, newList); }
    }
}
```

Comment: pls show MyClass, is it empty class?

Comment: is your custom class marked as serializable ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula it does not need to be; XmlSerializer does not check for that

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick: take your current code and wrap it in:

```
try {
    // create and use serializer
} catch(Exception ex) {
    while(ex != null) {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
    throw;
}
```

XmlSerializer actually gives you very detailed reasons when it can't serialize/deserialize something - but they are hidden in the inner-exceptions. With the above, you'll be able to see what the problem is in the debug output.

Usual suspects:

- type must be fully-public
- type must have a public parameterless constructor
- if the actual instance is a sub-class, that must be declared in advance